# HTML/CSS - Change color of inputbox if certain number of chars is entered

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of my inputbox, if a certain number of chars is written to it (e.g. if there are more than > 40 chars, the color of the inputbox border should change from green to red). 
My HTML Code:

```
<input type="text"  name="inputbox" placeholder="Enter Text" value=""  id="inputs">
```

The CSS Code:

```
 #inputs {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) inset;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #EAE7E7;
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    color: #777;
    font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 40px;
    width: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 140px;
}

#inputs:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #228B22 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #228B22 inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #228B22 inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #228B22 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #228B22 inset;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #228B22;
    outline: none;
}
```

Thanks for support!

Comment: I don’t think that is possible with HTML and CSS alone, you will need JavaScript for that.

Comment: @CBroe isn't it possible using media queries?

Comment: No problem for me using javascript. I just don't know what event I need in order to open a javascript function. 
Does the function need the name of the text field for changing its color?

Comment: On a side note, some of those CSS properties are available in every major browser without the need for vendor prefixes. Check http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the length:

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Use this to trigger the count:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    var className = main.className;
    main.onkeydown = function (e) {
        var el = e.currentTarget;
        el.className = (el.value.length > 10) ? className + " newClass" : className;
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.newClass{
    color: red;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axek4900/1/)**

Comment: If I use your code, I receive the following error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null"
I suppose this is because my text input is defined as an id instead of a class? (see CSS code above)

Comment: Instead of using a new class, I go with main.id = 'newID'. 
Where newID has a different color than the old id 'inputs'. Works for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvJJQL)

**Javascript**

```
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("b-input")[0];
    input.oninput = function() {
      if(input.value.length >=4) {
        if(!hasClass(this,"b-input_viewtype_error")) {
           input.className += " b-input_viewtype_error";
        }
      }
      else {
        input.className = "b-input";
      }
    }

   function hasClass(el, cls) {
     return el.className && new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + cls + "(\\s|$)").test(el.className);
   }
```

**CSS**

```
.b-input.b-input_viewtype_error {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="b-input" />
```